# Magento 2: After login how to get current quote id?

Tags: magento2, event-observer, quote, magento2.1.5

[Magento 2: After Customer Login Get Cart Information?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/171936/magento-2-after-customer-login-get-cart-information)

On observer I got 2 active quote id's. I can get by latest from `quote` table.

Is there any way to get current quote id?

Comment: The answer below is correct but copied from https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/106717/get-cart-quote-in-observer would recommend going to original source

Answer (score -2):

Please check with below code, i hope its work for you.

```
<?php

    namespace Adamsmage\Login\Observer;
    use \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
    use \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

    use \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session as CheckoutSession;

    class AddtoCart implements ObserverInterface {

        /** @var CheckoutSession */
        protected $checkoutSession;

        /**
         * @param CheckoutSession $checkoutSession
         */
        public function __construct(CheckoutSession $checkoutSession) {
            $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        }

        public function execute(Observer $observer) {
            /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor $product */
            $product = $observer->getProduct();

            /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote  */
            $quote = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote();
        }
    }
```

Comment: The answer below is correct but copied from magento.stackexchange.com/questions/106717/… would recommend going to original source – Dava Gordon