# Magento2 : Quote Value in Observer Gets NULL

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, checkout, event-observer

**Events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="payment_method_is_active">
        <observer name="ComapnyName_ModuleNames_DisabledCcByPincode" instance="ComapnyName\ModuleName\Model\Observer\DisabledCcByPincode" />
    </event>
</config>
```

**File Path : /app/code/CompanyName/ModuleName/Model/Observer/DisabledCcByPincode.phpDisabledCcByPincode.php**

```
<?php
namespace CompanyName\ModuleName\Model\Observer;

use \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Session;

class DisabledCcByPincode implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $checkoutSession;

    public function __construct(
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        Session $checkoutSession
    )
    {
        $this->_logger = $logger;
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
    }
    /**
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $result          = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();
        $method_instance = $observer->getEvent()->getMethodInstance();
        $quote           = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
        //$this->_logger->info($method_instance->getCode());
        /* Disable All payment gateway  exclude Your payment Gateway*/

        var_dump($quote); //This Value coming NULL

        $postcode = $quote->getShippingAddress()->getPostcode();

    }


}
```

I am not getting **quote** or any data except `$result`value. I would like to get quote data in above observer event.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have fixed an issue by following way,

```
<?php
namespace CompanyName\ModuleName\Model\Observer;

use \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;

class DisabledCcByPincode implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_cart;

    public function __construct(
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $_cart
    )
    {
        $this->_logger = $logger;
        $this->_cart = $_cart;
    }
    /**
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $result          = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();
        $method_instance = $observer->getEvent()->getMethodInstance();
        $quote           = $this->_cart->getQuote(); // Updated Code

        $postcode = $quote->getShippingAddress()->getPostcode();

    }


}
```

Comment: Is it possible to check `getShippingMethod()` and disable COD?

Comment: I found the solution here https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/189530/46716

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code

```
$quote = $observer->getQuote();
```

OR

```
<?php
namespace Marissen\Lease\Observer;

use \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

use \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session as CheckoutSession;

class AddtoCart implements ObserverInterface {

    /** @var CheckoutSession */
    protected $checkoutSession;

    /**
     * @param CheckoutSession $checkoutSession
     */
    public function __construct(CheckoutSession $checkoutSession) {
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer) {
        /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor $product */
        $product = $observer->getProduct();

        /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote  */
        $quote = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote();
    }
}
```

Source from [get cart/quote in Observer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/106717/get-cart-quote-in-observer)

Comment: I had already tried this with no success.

Comment: Checkoutsession should be workable.or else you need to find your mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Vishwas Soni,

Please change the code

> ```
> $postcode = $quote->getShippingAddress()->getPostcode();
> ```

to

> ```
> if($quote && null !== $quote){
>   $postcode = $quote->getShippingAddress()->getPostcode();
> }
> ```

**Donot use  checkout session,session bcoz  magento checkout magento using rest api,So you cannot  `Magento\Checkout\Model\Session` at rest api area**

Comment: Your answer seems to be irrelevant for me. Could you please read my question again and help me if you have any solution.

Answer (score 0):

this class `app/code/Magento/Payment/Model/Method/AbstractMethod.php` is having this dispatch event

in this event magento passes three parameter

```
[
  'result' => $checkResult,
  'method_instance' => $this,
  'quote' => $quote
]
```

So in your code you can get quote by below code

```
public function execute(Observer $observer)
{
    $result          = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();
    $method_instance = $observer->getEvent()->getMethodInstance();
    $quote           = $observer->getQuote(); // You will get Quote by this code

    $postcode = $quote->getShippingAddress()->getPostcode();

}
```

Comment: But somehow quote value seems to be NULL here. That's what I want to know, why quote is getting NULL here?